# Why does bootstrap include a rectangle box around my checkbox in this panel?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

Bootstrap includes a rectangle around the check box in this [jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/k19wj7pL/1/).  Have I used markup incorrectly or is there a work around?

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <div class="form-group form-group-lg">
        <label for="cbLabel" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Label:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <input type="checkbox" id="cbLabel" class="form-control" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: try to remove class in checkbox. is it problem for you?

Comment: I tried removing the class but it will not work.  I need the checkbox to stay the same size and stay in the same position.

Comment: Well unfortunately, the `form-control` class is exactly what's causing your problem. Notice how none of the checkboxes in the documentation use that class: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms

Comment: Is there another class that I can use that will keep the style and position?  I need to make sure to col-sm-3 is used.

Comment: Not really. As Shawn Taylor has shown bellow you can sort of hide the shadow that class creates, but you still wind up with a very wide area the user could accidentally click on to check the box. Truthfully, checkboxes really shouldn't be resized, and it can cause issues across various browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a custom class to the `form-control` element (`.fix` in my example) and some custom styling to override Bootstrap's styling.

```
.fix {
 -webkit-box-shadow: none;
 box-shadow: none;
}

.fix:focus {
-webkit-box-shadow: none;
box-shadow: none;
}
```

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" id="cbLabel" class="form-control fix">
```

Sample: http://www.bootply.com/61qJqP5whr

Comment: It gets rid of the shadow, but it introduces another problem: the user can click pretty far away from the box and still check the checkbox. Depending on what the checkbox is being used for, that could be pretty dangerous to have such a wide area to check the box.

Comment: that was the case before too, but it was more obvious. you could probably disable label-clicking somehow, but not sure, and not part of OP's question